# About global and local extrema for this function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

I have the function
$$f(x, y) = \ln(1 + xy) - \frac{1}{3}(x^2+y^2)$$
I found its critical points, one saddle and two maxima, the latter of which are
$$A = (1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}) \qquad \qquad B = -A$$

How can I say that those points are global maxima and not just local, without plotting the function? I thought about analysing what happens when $(x, y) \to (\pm \infty,\ \pm\infty)$ but there are times in which it's a mess.

In this case for example, I thought about studying what happens along the straight lines $x = y$, getting

$$f(x) = \ln(1+x^2) - \frac{2}{3}x^2 \sim 2\ln|x| - x^2$$

as $x \to \pm \infty$, and this either cases goes to $-\infty$.

Hence there is an upper limit and my points are global max. Is this reasoning correct? Or is it wrong and why?

Are there better / "righter" ways to proceed in general, when dealing with functions in two variables in the case of a non compact domain?

Comment: There's no general method to show that a local max is a global max. What you've shown is that there is no global min.

Comment: @J126 Uhm, ok! But then what can I do if the exercise asks me for "are those points local max or global max"?

Comment: There are two problem areas. The first is you need to show that as $(x, y)$ grows, that the function doesn't increase. You showed it along a specific curve. You need to show it works along all points. You can do this with the rays $(x, kx)$ for $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @J126 Can I say, in this case, that since I have a difference between a logarithm and a power, the power "wins" and thence the function values will always tend to $-\infty$?

Comment: Second, you have to worry about $(1, -1)$ and $(-1, 1)$ where the log doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, my original comment ignored the special points where the log doesn't exist.

Comment: @J126 Or also $$(x^2 + y^2)\left(\frac{\ln(1+xy)}{x^2+y^2} - \frac{1}{3}\right) \sim -(x^2 + y^2)$$

Comment: If this is a math class, using asymptotic ideas without a concrete computation is usually frowned upon, because intuition can sometimes fail you. As I said in my comment, you can explicitly examine all the curves $y = kx$ and show they all go to $-\infty$.

Comment: @J126 Yes, but you also said that those straight lines would be a special direction... How about $y = \alpha x^2$ or $y = b x^n$ and so on... I cannot test them all!

Comment: Ah, but I am showing that no matter which direction you head in, you will be decreasing in value. All the points on your curve $y = ax^2$ lie on one of my straight lines. Since $y = ax^2$ moves away from the origin, the function values must also tend toward $-\infty$.

Comment: @J126 Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. I should also mention that having an intuition for asymptotic behaviour is a marvelous tool, and will save you a lot of work if you already can see the answer. But, as we learn things in math it's always good to be able to back your intuition up.

Answer (score 1):

Showing that $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x,x)=-\infty$, you have just proved that the function has no global minimum.

In order to investigate $f$ at *infinity*, you may also use polar coordinates:
letting $x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$, we get
$$f(x,y)=\ln(1 + r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)) - \frac{r^2}{3}=
\ln\left(1 + \frac{r^2\sin(2\theta)}{2}\right) - \frac{r^2}{3}\leq \ln\left(1 + \frac{r^2}{2}\right) - \frac{r^2}{3}$$
and as $r$ goes to $+\infty$ the RHS goes to $-\infty$
$$\ln\left(1 + \frac{r^2}{2}\right) - \frac{r^2}{3}\sim 2\ln(r) - \frac{r^2}{3}\sim - \frac{r^2}{3}\to -\infty.$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{\|(x,y)\|\to +\infty}f(x,y)=-\infty.$$
Here you should also check  the limit at any point of the boundary of the (open) domain $D=\{(x,y): xy>-1\}$: if $(x_0,y_0)\in \partial D=\{(x,y): xy=-1\}$,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)}f(x,y)=\ln(0^+) - \frac{1}{3}(x_0^2+y_0^2)=-\infty.$$
Now we have established that the function has global maximum at the critical points $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}) $ and $(-1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2}) $.